# Swift: inheritance memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider this simple example:

```
class MemberClass {}
class SubclassA: SKSpriteNode {
    var member = MemberClass()
}

let test = SubclassA() // Everything OK
```

Now consider the same example with one additional layer of inheritance:

```
class MemberClass {}
class SubclassA: SKSpriteNode {}
class SubclassB: SubclassA {
    var member = MemberClass()
}

let test = SubclassB() // `member` is leaking
```

In the first example, everything is OK.
In the second example the `member` is for some reason leaking memory (?!).

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

*I've used `SKSpriteNode` as an example, but I think you can replicate the issue with pretty much every `NSObject` subclass.*

**Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)**

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886126/swift-3-ios-10-false-memory-leak-bug

Comment: Do report it to Apple. The more they hear about a thing, they more likely they are to fix it....